# How to prevent services from firing before user is authorized in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that is called to get the authorized user's location list. This information is used to populate a select list and they can switch locations to view different information.

The code for the select list is in the nav bar in the index.html but I don't want the service to fire on the page until after they user has been successfully authenticated and the app switches to the main view.

I'm using ng-show to hide the navigation bar with an isAuthorized() function for the AuthCtrl. However, the service call from the LocationCtrl to populate the ng-repeat always fires whether the user is logged in or not. I could move the nav component into the main view but then I'd need to have it in all the views that are protected. What is the best way to handle populating service-based menu items in a single page app?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="betterbooks">
<head>
  scripts...
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="AuthCtrl as auth">
    <div class="container" ng-show="auth.isAuthorized()">
      <ul class="navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#/home/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Accounts <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-controller="LocationCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="location in locations">
              <a href="#/location/{{ location.id }}/">
                 {{ location.name }} 
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li><button ng-click="auth.logout()">Logout</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="view-container" style="height:100%">
    <div ui-view class="view-frame"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ng-if` instead. The navbar won't be loaded into the dom until `auth.isAuthorized()` is true, so the `LocationCtrl` won't render or run until that point.